# User Input Batch File crashes @ echo var

Tags: batch-file, variables, user-input

I am writing a basic batch script and I need to acquire user input.
The script appears to crash when I call the user input vars in an echo command.
(This is probably something very basic but I can't see the error...)

```
@echo off
echo ********************************
echo    SHUTDOWN/RESTART
echo ********************************
echo.
set /p answer="Restart (R) or Shutdown(S)? "
set /p time="How soon ? "
echo you have selected %answer% in %time% seconds.
if "%answer%"=="" goto error
if "%time%"=="" goto error
if "%answer%"=="R" (
    goto restart 
) else (
    goto shutdown
)
echo.
echo.

:restart
FOR /L %%AA IN (1,1,%1) DO (
    echo Restarting in %%AA ...
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "call the user vars"?  Does that mean examine ```%answer%```, for example?  If that's the complete script, then unless you type R it's going to an undefined label.

Comment: The syntax of your `for /l` loop is wrong (`%%A` instead of `%%AA`). `%1` is the first parameter to your batchfile. It's probably empty, resulting in another syntax error. Your `echo` commands look fine.

Comment: Silly errors, thanks works fine now

Comment: You can't see the error for probably two reasons.  1) You are running the batch file with your mouse and the script closes when it errors out. 2) You have ECHO OFF at the top of your script.  When debugging batch files you always run them from the command prompt and turn ECHO ON.  And then you would have seen this: **%AA was unexpected at this time.**

Comment: Very useful thanks

Comment: On an unrelated note, `%time%` is already a system variable; I'd recommend naming it something else.

Answer (score 1):

The FOR command requires a single alphabetic character for its controlled variable.  `%AAA` is invalid.

Comment: Characters in the ACSII character table such as `#` are valid as a controlled variable character. "alphabetic" does not include characters like `#`.

Comment: @michael_heath - interesting, I did not know that. In my defence, I note the help text (```for /?```) says that the variable is "a single letter".

Comment: I see use of "letter" in `for /?`. The definition of a letter is vague in dictionaries, to be considered only of being alphabetical is uncertain due to a technicality. So while `#` can be used and is decimal 35 in ASCII table, if you wanted the 3rd token, you may have problems with `%`, which is decimal 37. It is easier to use any of A-Z and can be regarded as a letter that `for /?` mentions. ;)